# Sending multiple HTTP Response to a single HTTP Request in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to .NET and I want to develop the application which send multiple HTTP responses to the single HTTP Request.

Is there any way that I can store HTTP Handler on server which can be used when it is needed.

Comment: I'm very curious, why do you need multiple responses per request?  What client app?

Comment: dont thank in advance, thank by selecting answers to your old questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198287/single-request-to-multiple-asynchronous-responses
check out this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would break the HTTP standard by sending multiple responses to a request.

However, you can use Transfer-Encoding "chunked" which sends a response in multiple parts. In regular ASP.Net you would use `Response.Flush()` to achieve this.

I guess that you have to execute the `ActionResult` and send it manually with the response object to be able to send multiple parts in the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Static members persist across multiple requests, so you could do this:

```
public static class HttpHandlerStorage
{
    //  this should still be here, unless the HttpApplication reloads.
    public static IHttpHandler StoredHandler { get; set; }
}
```

However, your HttpContext will get destroyed at the end of the request.